# First loop of a Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I would like to run some code inside the first loop of a Parallel.ForEach. Only in the first loop whichever it is. The reason is to write some diagnostic data to disk that is produced by the code inside the loop. After the first loop data will be only kept in the memory and aggregated later.
Would this work?

```
bool firstLoop = true;
Parallel.ForEach(someList, 
    p=>
    {
        // do something here

        if (firstLoop)
        {
            firstLoop = false;

            // do something here for the first loop
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does it have to happen on the first item in the list or the first loop that's executed? Does the rest of the iterations rely on what's being done in that first loop?

Comment: No, this is not at all guaranteed to work.  The latency of `// do something here` can and will cause firstLoop to be examined at different points by different threads (because of the Parallel.ForEach) and could be updated multiple times.

Comment: I'd be inclined to run your special code directly over `someList.First()` before going parallel on `someList.Skip(1)`. Keep it simple and save yourself some nasty synchronization issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need something to happen on the first item, and the rest of the iterations don't rely on what's being done, you can use the following to see if you're processing the first item

```
if (p==items.First())
{
    //Do something
}
```

If you need to do something once that the rest of the loops will rely on then you can use a lock as suggested by David or you can do what you need before the Parallel.ForEach

So you could do

```
//Do stuff using someList(0)

Parallel.ForEach(someList.Skip(1), p=>
```

Comment: @Manngo the issue with `(p==someList.First())` is that it almost certainly will not execute in the first loop, it'll only execute in whatever loop contains the first item in the list.

Comment: Actually that is perfectly enough for me. I just assumed that the Parallel.ForEach starts with the first X items from the beginning. I need to mention here that I'm a hobby programmer so please forgive me for not giving the right explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, this will not be at all guaranteed to work.  One option would be to create a lock and only evaluate and update `firstLoop` inside the lock.  However, this would cause you to lose a some of your parallelism and would suggest that you look for a better approach, unless you do not have pressing needs around the time that it takes to complete the operation.

Keep in mind that this does not guarantee that `firstLoop` will be evaluated on the first item in your list, only that it will only be evaluated to true once.

```
var someList = new List<string>();
var obj = new object();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    someList.Add(i.ToString());
}

bool firstLoop = true;
var rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
Parallel.ForEach(someList,
    p =>
    {
        // do something here
        var next = rand.Next(1, 100);
        Thread.Sleep(next);
        lock (obj)
        {
            if (firstLoop)
            {
                firstLoop = false;
                firstLoop.Dump();
                // do something here for the first loop
            }
        }
    });
```